# ASP.NET MVC controller action restricted to a specific view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, action, restrict

Is there a way to restrict a controller action to be accessible only from a specific view? I have a Details page for a queried entity in my database and basically by a button and a simple JS confirmation prompt I would like to change few properties of this object and save it back to the database. I've developed a controller action method which does the job but I have no idea how to restrict access to it, so users cannot (un)intentionally modify entities by passing a specific url in the browser. I would like the action to be only accessible on this specific Details page, by pressing the designated button.
I tried using `[ChildActionOnly]` but it's only accessible from another action method, and not a view.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the referrer url (and perhaps return a error page of BadRequest if its not correct)

Comment: Thank you, that was a right direction to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)'s comment I've managed to get it working.

The button is a simple `Action Link`, which redirects to the restricted controller action:

```
public ActionResult ReturnBook(int id)
    {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        //code
    }
```

The method checks, if there is any `UrlReferrer` at all. Typing action url in the browser results in the referrer being null.
If the call is made by `ActionLink` from a View, the `UrlReferrer` is not null and optionally its property `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath` can be checked and compared to a desired url, from which the invoke can only be made. In my case, as I am not invoking this method anywhere else in my code, I stayed with just `null/notnull` condition.